# Dockerfile capture output of a command

Tags: docker

I have the following line in my Dockerfile which is supposed to capture the display number of the host:

```
RUN      DISPLAY_NUMBER="$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d: -f2)" && echo $DISPLAY_NUMBER
```

When I tried to build the Dockerfile, the DISPLAY_NUMBER is empty. But however when I run the same command directly in the terminal I get the see the result. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the `$DISPLAY` variable empty when you run `docker build`?

Comment: Yes! The DISPLAY_NUMBER is empty!

Comment: You can’t put that in a Dockerfile.  What would happen if you ran the image from a different host, or (given your other questions) from a different ssh session with a different `$DISPLAY`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host environment variables cannot be passed during build, only at run-time.

Only build args can be specified by:

first "declaring the arg"

```
ARG DISPLAY_NUMBER
```

and then running

`docker build . --no-cache -t disp --build-arg DISPLAY_NUMBER=$DISPLAY_NUMBER`

You can work around this issue using the `envsubst` trick

```
RUN      echo $DISPLAY_NUMBER
```

And on the command line:

```
envsubst < Dockerfile | docker build . -f -
```

Which will rewrite the Dockerfile in memory and pass it to Docker with the environment variable changed.

Edit: Note that this solution is pretty useless though, because you probably 
want to do this during run-time anyways, because this value should depend on not on where the image is built, but rather where it is run.

I would personally move that logic into your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` script.

Comment: That will pass the display number of the machine where the image is built and print it out during build. I doubt that this makes any sense. If I wanted to know the display number of my current machine, I would just run the command there.

Comment: I did not really consider the OP's intent, so in that sense your answer is probably more useful from a practical perspective. Although your answer has a small inaccuracy though, regarding as to why the variable is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Commands specified with `RUN` are executed when the image is built. There is no display during build hence the output is empty.

You can exchange `RUN` with `ENTRYPOINT` then the command is executed when the docker starts.

But how to forward the hosts display to the container is another matter entirely.